# Modify the address of a variable?

Tags: c++

In C++, how can I modify the pointer of a variable, e.g:

```
int x = 5;//holds 5
int y = 10;//holds 10
int *y_ptr = &y;//holds the address where 10 is stored

&x = y_ptr;//I want the address of x to be the same as the address of y
```

In the last line I am getting a compiler error, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can't have two variables in one address.

Comment: The address of a variable is readonly, you cannot change it.

Comment: @mpromonet: It should be tagged with whatever language the OP has a question about, apparently C++ in this case.

Comment: I don't see the reason for the down-votes in this one. It's a clearly asked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. Variables have a fixed address.

You have have two identifiers refer to the same variable by doing:

```
int x = 5;
int &y = x;
```

but you cannot later change `y` to identify some other variable.